# Android: Custom ViewPager in xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-custom-view

I'm trying to simply override one method of ViewPager and then use my custom class in XML, but my app is crashing every time I run it.

My Custom Class:

```
public class MainMenuViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private final String[] TITLES = {"One", "Two","Three", "Four", "Five"};

    public MainMenuViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MainMenuViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
        super.setCurrentItem(item);
        actionBar.setTitle(TITLES[item]);
    }
}
```

In XML:

```
 <com.example.android.example.TestActivity.MainMenuViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />
```

I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException at runtime.

The only thing worth noting is this Custom ViewPager is nested in another class. Is this a problem?

**EDIT:**
Still working on getting the runtime logcat exception, but when I go to graphical layout in Eclipse and look at error log I see this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.whatspoppin.android.whatspoppin.TestActivity$MainMenuViewPager.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:347)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

and at runtime:

```
08-07 16:43:30.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1723): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.example.TestActivity.MainMenuViewPager" on path: /data/app/com.example.android.example-2.apk
08-07 16:43:30.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1723): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.example.TestActivity.MainMenuViewPager" on path: /data/app/com.example.android.example-2.apk
08-07 16:43:30.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1723): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.example.TestActivity.MainMenuViewPager" on path: /data/app/com.example.android.example-2.apk
08-07 16:43:30.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1723):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
08-07 16:43:30.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1723):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-07 16:43:30.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1723):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-07 16:43:30.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1723):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
08-07 16:43:30.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1723):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
```

Comment: This is off-topic, but why do you implement a custom pager in the first place? What you have above can easily be done with a normal `ViewPager` and an `OnPageChangeListener`.

Comment: And **ALWAYS** include the logcat in your question if you get exceptions.

Comment: Are you sure that `com.example.android.example.TestActivity.MainMenuViewPager` is correct? Most likely the package name is wrong.

Comment: It is very much correct. I've changed it like 3 times to be sure. Well there's some other stuff I plan on doing in the ViewPager, this is just the first thing I'm testing out.

Comment: Yeah well then we need to see the logcat. Othwerwise we cannot identify the error.

Comment: Will update my post, just need to get my code back to where it was when I posted this.

Comment: Do you get the above exception in the Grapical editor in Eclipse or really from the logcat? Only the logcat errors are important.

Comment: Updated. It doesn't give anything else really though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just reread your question and the answer just hit me. I somehow missed that your custom `ViewPager` is an inner class of `TestActivity`. If you want to reference nested classes in XML you have to do it like this:

```
<com.example.android.example.TestActivity$MainMenuViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />
```

Comment: Just stepped away from my computer, but this looks like it will be the solution. I'll test it later and give you the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Does the inner class also have to be static?

Comment: Yes it always has to be static when used like this.